# PHP making sql script from array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have created an array with php.
The array looks like this:

```
array(37) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(43) "first title"
    ["images"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(57) "images/pathtiimage1.jpg"
      [1]=>
      string(57) "images/pathtoimage2.jpg"
      [2]=>
      string(57) "images/pathtoimage3.jpg"
      [3]=>
      string(57) "images/pathtoimage4.jpg"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(61) "second title"
    ["images"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(71) "images/pathtoimage1.jpg"
      [1]=>
      string(71) "images/pathtoimage2.jpg"
      [2]=>
      string(71) "images/pathtoimage3.jpg"
      [3]=>
      string(71) "images/pathtoimage4.jpg"
    }
  }
 etc.
```

My goal is to insert this data into a database, is it possible to create a sql script for this or do it directly from the same page I created this array?

EDIT
My database should look something like this
a table Products with an id obviously and the title
a second table images with the unique id and the right product id for every image since 1 product can have multiple images.

I also did an echo of the json_encode of this array, may be usefull?

Comment: Yes why not? Try it and see. If you can't get it to work then a lot of people on SO can help at *that* point

Comment: What's better to create a sql script or do it directly?

Comment: Whatever works best for you and is clean and secure. There is no set rule

Comment: Could you send me in the right direction if I wanted to create a script?

Comment: Script like how? Any code that you write will be a script. Any general idea of what you have in mind? You just have to write code to build and execute your desired query safely

Comment: Please edit/update your question and add your database structure because it is impossible for us to create the query right now.

Comment: Now everytime I refresh the page it recreates the array, would be nice to insert everything in my database as well when I refresh. I'm guessing I need to write my insert statements?

Comment: @Technoh I only have a database(localhost) no tables or anything setup, I'm thinking what is the best way to structure my database. 2 tables, titles & images and a relation between these tables?

Comment: @Technoh see edited OP

Comment: @FrankLucas Can a specific image be linked to more than one product?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can do that, as all frameworks (PHP or any other languages) are doing this to prevent direct SQL commands running.

But it's not that easy. You need to handle it in a general way. You have to specify tables that are related. For example you can have models like these:

```
class Product extends Model {
    $relations = array(
        'has_many' => array(
            'Image' => array(
                'foreign_key' => 'product_id',
            ),
        ),
    );
}

class Image extends Model {
    $relations = array(
        'belongs_to' => array(
            'Product' => array(
                'foreign_key' => 'product_id',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

I took the idea from PHP frameworks like laravel, CakePHP and other frameworks.

**BUT** I do not suggest you to implement all these stuff, while you can use implemented frameworks that have been tested and of course reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use some framework or they way frameworks do things.. But in case if you are trying to understand how to generate query (string) following code might be helpful. But its not a preferred way....

```
$ary = array (
    array 
    (
        "title"=> "first title",
            "images"=> array 
            (
            "images/pathtiimage1.jpg",
            "images/pathtoimage2.jpg",
            "images/pathtoimage3.jpg",
            "images/pathtoimage4.jpg"
                )
    ),
    array 
    (
    "title"=> "second title",
        "images"=> array 
            (
                "images/pathtoimage1.jpg",
                "images/pathtoimage2.jpg",
                "images/pathtoimage3.jpg",
                "images/pathtoimage4.jpg"
                )
    )
);

// Read array
foreach($ary as $product)
{
    // Generate query insert into proudcts (product_title) values($product["title"])..
    // Execute query...
    // get saved product id in same variable $product_id

    // read images array
    foreach ($product["images"] as $image)
    {
        // assign product_id to images table referrence key....
        // Generating sql insert query use $images to get value..
        // execute query
    }
}

?>
```